# Removing Application Verifier from c++ application

Tags: c++, application-verifier

I'm running into heap corruption with an application I'm developing, so I tried using Application Verifier to track it down, but now I can't seem to remove Application Verifier.

Running the original program loads the verifier automatically, removing it from application verifier or uninstalling application verifier didn't help.

The registry keys are my one lead, however I'm unsure what to do with them.

Comment: So there are no applications listed in your Application Verifier, but it still gets loaded into your application?

Comment: Yes, I've removed my application from the list and it still gets loaded into the application. Using process explorer, I can see that the two application verifier dlls are attached

Comment: Maybe you have two Application Verifiers installed, one as part of Windows SDK and another as standalone installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I had an application verifier as a part of the Windows SDK, as well as a standalone version. Another possible cause was I made sure I clicked 'save' after removing my application from the Application Verifier list.